# Can I publish in a field completely unrelated to my present field? If yes, what about affiliations?

Tags: publications, journals, independent-researcher, affiliation

I'm a scientific researcher working in material science and have a couple of good publications in reputed journals. However, I'm also very interested in topics like philosophy, psychology and political science. I have some written material in these fields which I want to publish, but I'm not sure how to proceed. What affiliation should I mention with my name, as I'm not connected to any university/institution presently.
Should I contact some academicians working in philosophy, psychology, political science & related fields and offer them to include their name in the publication if they like my manuscript?
Moreover, I would soon be commencing my PhD in my main stream. Will the above mentioned collaborations be detrimental to my academics?

Comment: "Should I contact some academicians working in philosophy, psychology, political science & related fields and offer them to include their name in the publication if they like my manuscript?" - Look up "gift authorship".

Comment: If it wasn't already clear from @Antonio's comment, the answer to that question is ***NO!***

Comment: You don't need any affiliation to publish - though the 'right' affiliations are known to make publishing easier. You can publish as a private individual too.

Comment: My general advice is to give your title and place of work.  Even if the publication is unrelated.  An exception would be if your employer forbids publication...

Comment: Another guess would be that a lot of amateurs submit papers in philosophy and psychology, with what are considered trivial remarks, or repeating mistakes of the past.  Of course if you know the literature of the area, you will avoid those traps, right?

Answer (score 5):

Should you ever include people as author for liking your manuscript? **No!**

Can you try to get in contact with an academic of your favourite field, discuss your ideas with him/her and ask if they'd like to write a publication with you? *Sure thing.*

Will publications in a foreign field hinder your main Phd? *Depends.*

Will you find the time to do both in parallel properly? If not, which has preference? If you do it before you start your main PhD or you are happy to develop that other paper slowly as a hobby, it may not affect your main work.

Will it affect your reputation in your main field? *For most people it should not have any impact at all.* A few may value your additional interests others may see this is a diversion or as a potential risk for you to jump ship and switch your research areas. But overall, I'd think those are few and they'd even themselves out. 
With respect to industry, many recruiters even claim they look for candidates that do something unconventional as a hobby/side interest. So in industry you may even win some minor bonus points.